# Retornar dias do ano, retirando os que estão em uma Variavel

Tags: php, data

Preciso de uma função em PHP que me retorne todos os dias do ano menos os que forem selecionados anteriormente.

Exemplo
Meu cliente selecionou ( **01/01,02/01,04/01,12/01,12/05,18/01,08/01,10/11,05/12,11/09,01/12** )

Ai preciso que gere todos os dias restantes para ser gravado no banco.

Pode ser em formato americano mesmo.

A lista acima e só um pequeno exemplo, pois poderá ser marcado ate 250 dias, assim restando poucos dias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode resolver esse problema com os seguintes passos, gerar um range de datas (o próprio calendário do ano) com a ajuda das classes [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) e [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) que define a unidade de incremento (PD1) do range.

Depois pegue o dia corrente do foreach e compare com a lista de exceções e faça que [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) pule eles, isso vai gerar a string SQL com vários values para executar apenas um insert ao final.

É **importante** comentar que o range de datas não inclui a data final no caso 31/12/2018 por isso a linha: `$dataFim->modify('+1 day');`. [`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) adiciona mais um dia a data que vira `01/01/2019`.

```
$dataInicio = new DateTime('2018-01-01');
$dataFim = new DateTime('2018-12-31');
$dataFim->modify('+1 day');
$intervalo = new DateInterval('P1D');

$diasAno = new DatePeriod($dataInicio, $intervalo, $dataFim);

$selecionados = '01/01,02/01,04/01,12/01';
$excecoes = explode(',', $selecionados);


foreach($diasAno as $date){
    if(!in_array($date->format('d/m'), $excecoes)){
        $sql .= sprintf("('%s'),", $date->format('Y-m-d'));
    }
}

$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
echo $sql;
```

A saída é algo como:

```
('2018-01-01'),('2018-01-02'),('2018-01-03'),('2018-01-04')
```